# Lightning Experience URL modifiers

Tags: lightning-experience

In lightning experience, when adding query parameters and reloading the page, they seem to be cleansed from the page on reload, however, fragment identifiers (or hashes) are persistent.

Ex:

```
https://sub-domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/app
```

If I add a query parameter:

```
https://sub-domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/app?query=potato
```

and reload the page, the params are cleared after the page reload.

However, if I add a hash:

```
https://sub-domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/app#query=potato
```

the hash is persists after a page reload...

Is there any reason why query parameters are removed when I reload my page vs hashes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is sent to the *server*, so technically it shouldn't be used in a Lightning App, or indeed any Single Page Application (but some types of apps do use this technique via the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), which lets you "fake" navigating between URLs). The hash string is only ever used by the *client*, and this is how Lightning remembers the current state of the app. There's no particular reason why it's cleared out that I know of, other than that's how it's designed to behave.